# How to print array of object in react

Tags: reactjs

I have below code for which

1. import React, { Component } from 'react';
       import factory from '../ethereum/factory';

   ```
   import ads_list from './ads_list'

   class showAds extends Component {
     static async getInitialProps(){
       let i;
       let a = [];
       const ad=await factory.methods.getAdress().call();
       const unique_address = Array.from(new Set(ad));
       for ( i = 0 ;i < unique_address.length;i++){
          a[i] = await factory.methods.getClientData(unique_address[i]).call();
       }
      console.log(a);
      return {a};
    }

    render(){
       return <div>
                <p>{}</p>
             </div>;
       }
    }

    export default showAds;
   ```

for the above code I am getting below values in console.

```
   [ 
      {
        '0': 'www.google.com', 
        '1': 'Click here and enjoy searching', 
        '2': '17' 
      },
      { 
        '0': 'www.gmail.com', 
        '1': 'PLease login here', 
        '2': '2' 
      } 
      { 
       '0': 'www.google.com',
       '1': 'Click here and enjoy searching',
       '2': '17' 
      },
      { 
       '0': 'www.gmail.com',
       '1': 'PLease login here', 
       '2': '2' 
      } 
    ]
```

The problem I am facing is to print these values in front-end.

Comment: Can you provide correct data as array you mention is not valid

Comment: You can use this simple react component `data => <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Do you want to print them all together or individually?

Comment: is your data similar to this object and array of it

`"Result" :  [
    {'0': 'www.google.com'}, 
    {'1': 'Click here and enjoy searching'}, 
    {'2': '17'}
]`

Comment: OP, what have you tried? What specific troubles are you having in showing the data? This question almost sounds like you're asking how to use React

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using a simpler `data` as an example, you can render an unordered list like so:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const data = [
      {
        "0": "www.google.com",
        "1": "Click here and enjoy searching",
        "2": "17"
      },
    ];

    return (
      <ul>
        {data.map(item => {
          return <li>{item[0]}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

CodeSandbox example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/j3y3q9pwr3

Answer (score 3):

```
JSON.stringify(["a", { b: "c" }])
```

See a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/print-data-on-react-qnxeo).