# how to loop through array that contain objects and check that each value equals null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am using `16.9.0`

I have the below array and i want to check that each object value is equal to `null`. If that is the case return do something, or just return`"Yes"`.

```
const data = [
   {0: {country: null}},
   {1: {name: null}},
   {2: {address: null}},
]
```

what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Sorry for the question but i am coming from a `python` background.

Any help would be very helpful.

Comment: Wellcome to react, try to search for the same kind of questions before asking.
Here you go with same
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49919070/how-to-print-array-of-object-in-react

Comment: You sure that's the actual shape of your data? That would mean you need to access `country` with `data[0][0].country`, `name` with `data[1][1].name`, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.every` function, you can check if all values are `null` or not.

```js
const data = [
  { 0: { country: null } },
  { 1: { name: null } },
  { 2: { address: null } },
];

const result = data.every((item) =>
  (Object.values(item).every((subItem) =>
    (Object.values(subItem).every(nodeItem => nodeItem == null)))
  )
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `(Object.values(subItem).every(nodeItem => nodeItem == null)))` only this line is necessary. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out javascript .map() Funktion for Arrays

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Then just use an If statement to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use single and simple `for` loop.

```js
const data = [
   {0: {country: null }},
   {1: {name: null }},
   {2: {address: null }},
];

const isEveryNull = (arr) => {
   for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (Object.values(arr[i][i]).some((q) => q !== null)) return false;
   }
   
   return true;
};

console.log(isEveryNull(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
   {0: {country: null}},
   {1: {name: null}},
   {2: {address: null}},
   {3: {address: "INDIA"}},
]
data.map((item,index)=>{
let varOne = item[index]
let key = Object.keys(item[index])[0]
if(varOne[key]===null){
console.log('This proparty is null')

}else{
console.log(varOne[key])
}



})
```

You can also do it like this.